# Displacing an enumerable by a count

Tags: c#, iterator

What I mean by displacing an enumerable is skipping the first `n` items, then returning the next `n` items, then returning the first `n` items, then returning the rest of the enumerable.

What do you think?  Does this idea have any value?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnumerableDisplacer
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Displace<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int displaceCount)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        var counter = 0;
        var displacedItems = new LinkedList<T>();
        while (counter < displaceCount)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            ++counter;

            displacedItems.AddLast(enumerator.Current);
        }

        counter = 0;
        while (counter < displaceCount)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            ++counter;

            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }

        foreach (var di in displacedItems)
        {
            yield return di;
        }

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `List` would use less memory and almost certainly be faster than a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Do you have an idea what it is you think it's going to be useful for?

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and outputs of your proposed Displace function

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is missing some basic validation. A public method should always validate its passed in arguments. Assume an `IEnumerable<int>` will be passed containing `10` elements

with `displaceCount == 10`. You won't see an exception if it is a "true"  `IEnumerables<int>` but you will receive wrong results.

A test with

```
IEnumerable<int> source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
source = source.Where(i => i > 0);
EnumerableDisplacer dispatcher = new EnumerableDisplacer();
var result = dispatcher.Displace(source, 10).ToList();
```

will result in a `List<int>` containing the **20** elements `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`

passing

```
IEnumerable<int> source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
EnumerableDisplacer dispatcher = new EnumerableDisplacer();
var result = dispatcher.Displace(source, 10).ToList();
```

will result in an `InvalidOperationException` in the second `while` loop at `yield return enumerator.Current;` because the enumeration has ended already.

You have two choices to do the input validation:

- checking the count of items contained in `source` against `displacedCount` which will result for a "true" `IEnumerable<T>` in iterating over the elements twice

or

- convert the `source` to an collection type like e.g an array and check its `Length` property against `displacedCount` which will result in iterating over the elements twice  as well.

I would go with the second choice because it would make the whole method easier (IMO) because you wouldn't need any other datastructure like the `LinkedList`.

This would result in

```
public class EnumerableDisplacer
{

    public IEnumerable<T> Displace<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int displaceCount)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        var sourceArray = source.ToArray();
        var doubledDisplacedCount = displaceCount * 2;
        if (sourceArray.Length < doubledDisplacedCount)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source", "The source needs to contain twice as many elements than displacedCount");
        }

        return DisplaceEx<T>(sourceArray, displaceCount);
    }
    private IEnumerable<T> DisplaceEx<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int displaceCount)
    {

        var doubledDisplacedCount = displaceCount * 2;

        for (var i = displaceCount; i < doubledDisplacedCount; i++)
        {
            yield return sourceArray[i];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < displaceCount; i++)
        {
            yield return sourceArray[i];
        }
        for (var i = doubledDisplacedCount; i < sourceArray.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return sourceArray[i];
        }

    }
}
```

---

What advantage should this method get from beeing `virtual` ? I don't see any. Overriding this method in an inherited class doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: While materializing the query makes it easier, it also removes functionality.  It's opposed to a LINQ-esque style of programming where items in a sequence are deferred as much as possible, increasing the memory footprint and either performing work that may not be necessary, or at least performing work before it is necessary.  The OP's approach provides that functionality (at the code of needing a bit more code to do so).  All that needs to happen to deal with a smaller input sequence is to check the return value of `MoveNext` when iterating.

Comment: @Servy I basically agree, but assume the OP feeds a source containing 100.000 items with a `displacedCount == 60.000` then a lot of work is done before it comes to `MoveNext`. And how should the OP deal with such a scenario. `MoveNext` would return `false` but a lot of items are `yielded` and maybe processed already. I know that my version isn't the best either, because it does the validation inside the "main"  method instead of passing the validated parameters to the "main"  method. (I will add this to my answer)

Comment: The solution is simply to replace the first two calls to `enumerator.MoveNext()` with `if(!enumerator.MoveNext()) yield break;` and you're done.

Comment: And then the caller of the code thinks that the method had succeeded which is wrong

Comment: Depends on what the expected behavior is.  I don't see how the behavior that would result would be wrong at all, in the same way that if you call `Skip(10)` on a sequence with `5` items it just yields no items, it doesn't throw an exception.  It doesn't need to.  It has an entirely sensible behavior.  The same is true of the OP's code.

Comment: In the way I read the description of the OP I would expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: So you consider all of the following .NET methods broken: `Skip`, `Take`, `SkipWhile`, `TakeWhile`?  Reading the description of the method I would only really ever think it would make sense to throw for a negative count value, any other value has a sensible behavior.

Comment: How about `Enumerable.ElementAt` which throws an exception if `MoveNext == false` ? And I didn't say broken I said that I would expect an exception beeing thrown. Maybe we should agree that we disagree.

Comment: What *could* `ElementAt` return if the sequence doesn't contain that many items?  It has no sensible behavior, so it has no choice besides throwing.  On the other hand, "the next X items from the sequence" can sensibly return all of the items it has, even if it's less than X.  That's in line with the established standards, unlike your code, which deviates from the standard implementation, and also removes other unrelated functionality (deferred execution) in order to remove the functionality of providing any non-negative count.  There's no *advantage*, just more disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what purpose you'd have for this.  But using combinations of `Skip`  `Take` and `Concat`, you could accomplish the same thing in one `foreach` block:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Displace<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int displaceCount)
{
    foreach(T t in source.Skip(displaceCount).Take(displaceCount).Concat(source.Take(displaceCount)).Concat(source.Skip(displaceCount * 2)))
    {
        yield return t;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're iterating the source sequence multiple times here.  That's not appropriate in a general purpose operation like this.  The source sequence may not contain the same elements when iterated multiple times, it may cause side effects when iterated, or it may simply perform complex operations that shouldn't be performed multiple times.

Comment: On a side note, you really need to use more line breaks in your queries.